# Magento customer login fails getting password hash

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

While debugging a customer login issue i am facing following behaviour:

Method getPasswordHash() returns an empty string in loginPost action of customer controller.

So far i am at customer model. But getPasswordHash seems to be a generic method (and useto return db value, customer data is however present)

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
    if (!$hash) {
        return false;
}
```

suggestions are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Issue becomes temporary fixed when i clean up cookies and become a new session. However it appears over and over

Comment: There's not quite enough context here to give an appropriate answer. Can you update your question with the login issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Also, there should be `return Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($password, $hash);` at the bottom of your validatePassword() method. (Did you forget to copy that part?)

Comment: Error message is the common "invalid username or password". validatePassword method is only partially copied, to show where ive been. At this point i got empty $hash and not so much clue about the mentioned getter.

Answer (score 1):

`getPasswordHash()` returns the hash value from the database.

Run this query in your db:

```
select e.email, v.value from customer_entity e join customer_entity_varchar v on e.entity_id=v.entity_id join eav_attribute a on v.attribute_id=a.attribute_id where attribute_code='password_hash' and e.email='customer_email_here';
```

It should show a hash value for the given customer email. If there's nothing there, then the problem is with your database.

If you do see hash values in the database, then it might be an extension that is conflicting with your setup. I would check if any extension is overriding classes from `Mage\Customer` and resolve those conflicts. You could also have modified code in `app\code\local\Mage` that is changing the default behavior.

Comment: your query returned correct result, as i said before, data is present. I keep my code/local clean. Also no rewrites for any customer model found in xmls. but thanks anyway